# Angular JS Datepicker not binding value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in my html and my input is empty without any value, although the html tag "value" has some value.

```
<input id="DataCompra" value="07/10/2014" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" 
       name="DataCompra" type="text"
       close-text="Fechar" 
       data-val="true" 
       data-val-date="The field Data Compra must be a date." 
       data-val-required="O campo Data Compra é obrigatório." 
       date-type="string" 
       datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" 
       is-open="DataCompra.open" 
       ng-click="DataCompra.open = true" 
       ng-model="DataCompra.dt" 
       show-button-bar="false" 
       show-weeks="false">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Controller ,

```
$scope.DataCompra.dt = new Date('2014-10-07');
```

remove `value` attribute from the Html part,

may be this will also work,

add new `directive` like this

```
<input id="DataCompra" value="07/10/2014" ng-init="DataCompra.dt = '2014-10-07' .....
```

remove value attribute from the Html part,')"

Comment: Isn't there any other way to solve it? I'm using asp net mvc 4, I can't remove the Value from html

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me

```
<input type="text" data-provide="datepicker"  class="form-control" data-ng-model="Date" name="Date" id="inputDate">

$('#inputDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    alert("selected date is " + $(ev.target).val());
    $scope.Date = ev.date;
});
```